# Titanium module for beacons

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, ibeacon, beacon

is anybody knows if there a beacon detector module for sdk 7?

Liferay, and altbeacon are not updated and i'm starting to despair.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this fork of liferay: https://github.com/garymathews/liferay-android-beacons

It is ready for 7.0 and has a binary in the [release section](https://github.com/garymathews/liferay-android-beacons/releases)